# Comparing two dictionaries Key values and return a new dictionary with the differences

Tags: python, dictionary

What I want to do is to compare two dictionaries:

```
predict = {'eggs': [1,2],'ham': [1,2,3], 'sausage': [1,2,3]}
actual = {'eggs': [2], 'ham': [1,2]}
```

and return a new dictionary of the difference:

```
difference = {'eggs': [1],'ham': [3], 'sausage': [1,2,3]}
```

What would be an efficient way (for large amount of data) to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the way you're currently doing it, and what's the specific efficiency problem you're having?

Comment: Then see https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. Any basic tutorial will cover list and dictionary handling.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [`set.difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) and `dict` comprehension:

```
>>> predict = {'eggs': [1,2],'ham': [1,2,3]}
>>> actual = {'eggs': [2], 'ham': [1,2]}
>>> difference = {k: list(set(v).difference(actual[k])) if k in actual else v for k, v in predict.items()}
{'eggs': [1], 'ham': [3]}
```

Explanation:

- You iterate over `predict` key-value pairs
- The new `difference` dictionary will have the same keys as `predict` and `actual`
- But its values will be the `set difference` of the current lists
- `set(v).difference(actual[k])` - As the keys are the same, you can access `actual[k]` and find its difference with the current one (which is `v`)
- Finally, you cast your result set with the difference to a list to have an output as requested.

Comment: how about the slightly different scenario below:

    predict = {'eggs': [1,2], 'ham': [1,2,3], 'sausage': [1,2]}
    actual = {'eggs': [2], 'ham': [1,2]}

I want to return a new dictionary:

    {'eggs': [1], 'ham': [3], 'sausage': [1,2]}

Comment: @ChrisLin I've just edited my answer with a check for this scenario. Thanks for pointing it out, I haven't thought about it.

Comment: One concern is that the set difference is slow for a large amount of data. Is there a more efficient way than set difference? @wencakisa

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
difference = {}
for key, value in predict.items():
    difference[key] = [el for el in predict[key] if (key not in actual) or (el not in actual[key])]

print(difference)
```

**edit:**
code was update to handle missing categories in the actual list

Comment: How should the code be if there is a susage in predict dictionary? @Philip Blonde

Comment: I have updated the code. Essentially the same, you just add a check for missing key values in actual.

Comment: For large dictionaries, the code will take hours to run. Is there a faster way to do this? @Philip Blonde Thanks.